# Upload de imagem sem fazer refresh da pagina

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte codigo que permite escolher um ficheiro e fazer o upload(VER IMAGEM)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]. eu tenho um formulario com varios inputs e no final é possivel fazer o upload de uma imagem. o problema que se passa com o meu codigo é que ao fazer o upload emite um echo mesmo em vez de simplesmente fazer o upload na mesma pagina, acabando por perder tudo o que foi escrito no formulario.

Codigo HTML do formulario:

```
    <form class="addform" name="ContactForm" action="addDataAdmin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">

            ISBN:
            <input type="text" name="ISBN">
            <br> Author's Name:
            <input type="text" name="Authorsname">
            <br> Title:
            <input type="text" name="Title">
            <br> Edition:
            <input type="number" name="edition">
            <br> Year:
            <input type="text" name="year" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)">
            <br> Category:
            <select name="category" size="1">
                <option value="computing">Computing</option>
                <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
                <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
            </select>
            <br> Publisher:
            <input type="text" name="publisher">
            <br> Quantity-in-stock:
            <input type="number" name="quantityinstock">
            <br> Price:
            <input type="text" name="price" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)">
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>

Codigo em PHP para fazer o upload.
<?php
    include("config.php");


$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["name"] );
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo ( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

if (isset ( $_POST ["submit"] )) {
    $check = getimagesize ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"] );
    if ($check !== false) {
        $message = "File is an image - " . $check ["mime"] . ".";
                echo "<script>alert('$message'); window.location.href='adminpage.html';</script>";
        echo "File is an image - " . $check ["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

     if(isset($_POST["send"])){


        $ISBN =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ISBN']);
        $Authorsname=$conn ->real_escape_string($_POST['Authorsname']);
        $Title= $conn ->real_escape_string($_POST['Title']);
        $edition= $conn ->real_escape_string($_POST['edition']);
        $year= $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
        $publisher= $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['publisher']);
        $category=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
        $quantityinstock=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['quantityinstock']);
        $price= $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
        $Image = $conn->real_escape_string ( file_get_contents ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"]));


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE ISBN =?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$ISBN);
        $ISBN = $_POST['ISBN'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0){
            echo $message = "ISBN already exists";
                echo "<script>alert('$message'); window.location.href='adminpage.html';</script>";

        }else{

            $ustmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO books (ISBN, Authorsname, Title, edition, year, publisher, category, quantityinstock, price, Image) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $ustmt->bind_param("sssiissiis",$ISBN,$Authorsname,$Title,$edition,$year,$publisher,$category,$quantityinstock,$price, $Image);
            $ISBN = $_POST['ISBN'];
            $Authorsname = $_POST['Authorsname'];
            $Title = $_POST['Title'];
            $edition = intval($_POST['edition']);
            $year = intval($_POST['year']);
            $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $quantityinstock = intval($_POST['quantityinstock']);
            $price = intval($_POST['price']);
            $Image = $_POST['Image'];
            $ustmt->execute();

     if($ustmt->affected_rows > 0)
     {
        echo $message = "You have succefully added a new book";
                echo "<script>alert('$message'); window.location.href='adminpage.html';</script>";

        }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error';

            }
        }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Como?nao entendi,desculpe

Comment: Nesta outra pergunta já foi discutido o que você quer fazer, basta você analisar a resposta e adaptá-la para o seu problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar imagem ao selecioná-la e mostrar miniatura sem dar refresh na pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5581/enviar-imagem-ao-selecion%c3%a1-la-e-mostrar-miniatura-sem-dar-refresh-na-pagina)

Comment: O que o `echo` retorna?